# pass a ng-template defined in one component to another component?

Tags: javascript, angular, components, angular2-template, ng-template

is it possible to use a ng-template defined in the template of one component, in another component? Passing the name of the ng-template

```
  @Component({
  selector:'component1'
  template:`

     <ng-template #template1>
         <div class="test">
          <h1>component 1</h1>
        </div>
       </ng-template>`  

       <component2 [nameOfTemplate]='template1'></component2>

  })


  @Component({
  selector:'component2'
  template:`

    <!-- Template defined in other component -->
     <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="nameOfTemplate">
     </ng-container>`  

  }) 
export Class Component2{
   @input nameOfTemplate;  
}
```

Comment: It's possible. For a more elaborate answer you'd need to provide the information how the components are related.

Comment: Hi, one component calls the other (it is inside it) and passes the name of the ng-template to a variable

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: in component 2 it is not rendering anything, however if I copy the ng-template and paste it in component 2 if it renders

Comment: Please create a minimal reproduction in http://stackblitz.com

Comment: ok, an example:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vxcv8q

Comment: I got it thanks, it was going through the name of the template
[template]='template1' instead of  [template]=template1